# Opening other application from my own app

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I know that this question was asked and answered many times, but i cant find those answers useful to my program so i decided to ask another as my own. So i have two applications `AppA` and `AppB`, i want to open a certain activity of `AppA` from `AppB` here's my code for `AppB` :

```
public class AppB extends Activity {

static Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

}

public void openNoti(View v) throws NameNotFoundException {

    Intent i;
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.stealth.AppA");
        if (i == null)
            throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", 1000).show();

    }
}
}
```

Im sure that i am invoking the right package name or address of `AppA`, but it just cant find it, saying that i might have not declared it on my `Manifest.xml`.

Here's Manifest for `AppB` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stealth"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.stealth.AppB"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the manifest of `AppA` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stealth"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.stealth.AppA"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the problem is with the **package** you are calling for

you have same name in two apps package `com.example.stealth`

and you are calling

`"com.example.stealth.AppA"` which is not there

Now rename `AppA` package to  `"com.example.stealth.AppA"`  it will work